# Hidden field is undefined on Edge and other browser

Tags: javascript, undefined, microsoft-edge

I Team below javascript code working fine on IE 7,8,9 but not in Edge

```
function showSavings(expandTag, collapseTag, detailsTag, showSavingsTag, beneficiaryId, value) {

    detailsTag.style.display = (value == true ? 'block' : 'none');
    expandTag.style.display = (value == true ? 'none' : 'block');
    collapseTag.style.display = (value == true ? 'block' : 'none');
    showSavingsTag[0].value = (value == true ? 'true' : 'false');
    if (value == true)
    {
        addShownBeneficiary(beneficiaryId)
    }
    else
    {
        removeShownBeneficiary(beneficiaryId);
    }       

}
```

any idea what needs to be corrected to support Edge and other browsers?

Comment: are `detailsTag` etc DOM elements? if so, what is `runtimeStyle` property

Comment: runtimeStyle  -> is to display style .

Comment: ahhh .. wow, `runtimeStyle` was a MicroS#!t thing ... just use `style` instead - then it will work on every browser that is less than 20 years old

Comment: style not working on Edge

Comment: what's the error in the developer tools console (it DOES work on edge, you just did it worng)

Comment: of course, you may need to explain what `expandTag` etc are ... like show how you're calling `showSavings` function - and what the arguments are

Comment: This function is called by clicking Expand/Collapse button from code behind
spnExpandDetails.Attributes.Add("onclick", "showSavings(" + spnExpandDetails.ClientID + "," + spnCollapseDetails.ClientID + "," + divDetails.ClientID + "," + hdnShowSavings.ClientID + ",'" + dataRow["row_id"].ToString() + "',true);");
        spnCollapseDetails.Attributes.Add("onclick", "showSavings(" + spnExpandDetails.ClientID + "," + spnCollapseDetails.ClientID + "," + divDetails.ClientID + "," + hdnShowSavings.ClientID + ",'" + dataRow["row_id"].ToString() + "',false);");

Comment: IE7 and IE 8 its working but not in Edge .on developer console its not showing any error

Comment: `showSavings(" + spnExpandDetails.ClientID` ... so, in ASP a `ClientID` string has a `runtimeStyle` property in IE7 etc? I find that hard to believe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190446/discussion-between-kumarjcet-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: If you are using runtimeStyle property than it will not going to work in MS Edge. I can see that you had mentioned that style property is not working on Edge. I suggest you to make a separate test with style property in MS Edge to check whether it is working or not. If it worked than try to find any difference and try to correct it in your original code may help you to fix the issue. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/runtimeStyle